# Get Video file metadata in Java

Tags: java, video, metadata

I have been trying to find a way to get the metadata out of video files such as frame rate, length, codec, aspect ratio.  What java libraries are out there that would be good for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [VLCJ (GPL license)](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/)

VLCJ wraps around libVLC DLL library (the library used in VLC) via JNA for Java app. It supports reading the metadata from a media file via `MediaPlayer.getMediaMeta()`

Take note: certain versions of VLCJ don't work in full functionality with certain versions of libVLC. For example, VLCJ 1.2.x only works perfectly well with libVLC 1.2.0 (which is not released yet - a nightly build at the moment). If you use it with libVLC 1.1.x, it won't be able to read media file metadata via `MediaPlayer.getMediaMeta()`. In this case, you need to get the correct libVLC library for VLCJ version you choose.

http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/WhichVersion

VLCJ 1.2.x has some design changes when compared to VLCJ 1.1.x which may frustrate seasoned developer of VLCJ but it is for the good reasons.

Comment: I had serious troubles with VLCJ 1.2.x since recent unreleased versions of VLC were not working for me (videos are crashing after a couple of frames). I think that we can't consider VLCJ 1.2.x for professionnal projects until libVLC 1.2.0 reach the "stable" mention. It's like choosing between "good api + bad vlc" and "bad api + good vlc".

Comment: Starting with VLCJ 1.2.2, libVLC version-checking has been enforced. Still, you can use the last **VLCJ 1.2.0** version as long as you don't really use a few features that don't work without libVLC 1.2.x. For streaming media, it is fine with the latest stable libVLC 1.1.11. However, getting media file metadata is apparent one of a few that doesn't work (with a warning given)