# Regarding Geotagged videos & information provided by the video in the terms of gis

Tags: java, geolocation, gis, geocoding, geospatial

what is geotagged videos ?
Is it possible to get latitude and longitude  value from geotagged videos through coding ??
is there any api in java for executing this kind of videos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically [Geo-tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging) are just metadata entries on the file.

For code, I suppose you could check [metadata-extractor from google code](http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/source/browse/Samples/com/drew/metadata/GeoTagMapBuilder.java?r=aa90c86815aea7dbb12e1a4cac93362311240573), or see older question in here for general [Get Video file metadata in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380425/get-video-file-metadata-in-java)